# Dynamically add light sources (via shader) in deferred rendering path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cg

I am currently writing a gpu based particle system and am currently stuck at trying to achieve light emitting particles (such that the scenes gets lit as well).

I am generating a combined mesh of quads (one per particle) and tried to use the emission property of the gbuffer output in a fragment shader, but this does only result in glowing particles (in conjunction with a bloom camera effect), that do not light the environment. (The mesh is rendered with Graphics.DrawMesh)

Another thing I tried was using Graphics.DrawProcedural (by generating quads using a geometry shader, instead of using a precalculated mesh). In general I preferred this approach, but I couldn't even achieve a glowing effect this way (I dont't exactly know why :/ ).

Is there a way to dynamically add light sources (maybe via a shader that takes a compute buffer containing the positions as input) before the lighting pass happens? Or maybe another approach I've missed to far?

Thanks in advance :)

<strike>Edit: Maybe DynamiGI.SetEmissive can be used somehow?</strike>

Edit 2: This is an example of what I would like to achieve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPLeUNddCoM

Edit 3 (for those interested in my findings until now): DynamicGI cannot be used, as the "realtime" GI is also precomputed and only works for static GameObjects. Also there seems to be no way to dynamically illuminate the scene without a round-trip via the CPU: the particle data has to be copied back to the CPU and then ... (I don't really know, you could activate a bunch of point lights, what is not really pleasant regarding performance). Looking at the video I posted, it looks like the particle data is copied back to the cpu to update a rendered mesh at runtime (at 0:17 you can see a bunch of quads in the editor, I suppose one for each particle). This was the point where I thought I could use DynamicGI.SetEmissive, but I can't.